# What is the output of the below python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def myfunc(n):
  return abs(n - 50)

thislist = [100, 50, 65, 82, 23]
thislist.sort(key = myfunc)
print(thislist)
```

The output of the above line of code is ->> **[50, 65, 23, 82, 100]**
I don't understand how the **abs** function in code line
`return abs(n - 50)` is giving the above output.

Comment: How about you calculate `abs(n - 50)` for each of the numbers in the output and see what you notice?

Comment: Because its sorting your original values from smallest to largest AFTER going through your key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, understand this:

```
thislist = [100, 50, 65, 82, 23]
thislist.sort()
print(thislist)
```

The above code sorts the list and produces this output:

```
[23, 50, 65, 82, 100]
```

Now, when we use `thislist.sort(key = myfunc)`, `sort` uses the provided `key` to sort elements of `thislist`.

Now back to `myfunc`:

```
def myfunc(n):
   return abs(n - 50)
```

`abs` returns a number's "absolute value": `abs(8) == abs(-8) == 8`. In short, `abs()` always gives us positive result.

**Now, back to your main question.**

```
def myfunc(n):
   return abs(n - 50)

thislist = [100, 50, 65, 82, 23]
thislist.sort(key = myfunc)
```

While sorting, every element is passed to `myfunc`. For example, at first 100 is passed, and the result is 50, as `abs(100-50) = 50`. Next, 50 is passed, and the result is 0, as `abs(50-50) = 0`.

Similarly:

```
abs(65-50) == 15
abs(82-50) == 32
abs(23-50) == 27
```

It is on the basis of these results that your list is sorted. The element that appears first in the sorted list is 50, because it had the lowest return value when it was passed to `myfunc` (0). The next element is 65, because `myfunc(65)` had the second-lowest value (15). And so on.

The sorted list is `[50, 65, 23, 82, 100]` because the resulted `list` as processed by `myfunc` is `[0,15,27,32,50]`. It was on this basis that your original `list` got sorted.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. I am new to coding. Is this too simple for a StackOverflow post?

Comment: If you are new to coding, never stop asking about any problem you face. Its simple but main thing is if you don't ask how you get to know that what is it.... Keep Learning, Best of Luck

Answer (score 3):

`abs` is supposed to return the distance of a number from `0`.
For example:

```py
abs(10)               # result will be 10.
abs(5 - 10)           # --> abs(-5) --> result will be 5.
```

So, it will work like this:

```py
abs(100 - 50)   # Result will be 50, which is the highest, so 100 will be the last in the list.
abs(50 - 50)    # Result will be 0, which is the lowest so 50 will be first in the list.
abs(65 - 50)    # Result will be 15, so 65 will be the second on the list.
abs(82 - 50)    # Result will be 32, so 82 will be the fourth on the list.
abs(23 - 50)    # Result will be 27, so 23 will be the third on the list.
```

Notice that it return the list **sorted by the key, this time your function** the key doesn't change the values of the list. Only sort them.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. I am new to coding. Is this too simple for a StackOverflow post?

Comment: Yes, I am sorry it is a bit simple, you could find explaining by just searching in google, "How sort by key work in python". Next time take some time and try to find the answer alone :)

Answer (score 0):

Imagine the position of list items is mapped with `abs(n-5)` version of the list. Then sort the `abs(n-5)` list keeping the mapping intact.

`The list -> [100, 50, 65, 82, 23]`

`abs(n-5) -> [ 50,  0, 15, 32, 27]`

---

**Sort abs(n-5)**

`The list -> [50,  65, 23, 82, 100]`  <- *resultant list after sort*

`abs(n-5) -> [ 0,  15, 27, 32, 50 ]`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. I am new to coding. Is this too simple for a StackOverflow post?